# How can a vector reserve memory for object containing inner vector?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

Let say I've an object like this:

```
struct MyObject
{
    int someId;
    std::vector<int> innerVector;

    MyObject(int a)
    {
        innerVector.reserve(a);
    }
};
```

and I try to reserve a vector of `MyObject` this way:

```
std::vector<MyObject> myObjects;
myObjects.reserve(maxItemsToBeAllowed);
```

how can it reserve memory if the size of `innerVector` vector on each `MyObject` is unpredictable?
Does it just "try" and in case of larger `innerVector` reallocate at runtime?

Comment: It doesn't reserve any memory for the vector's class members. Once each `MyObject` actually exists it now becomes possible to reserve its vector's size. But only its vector's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the guts of a `std::vector` are likely stored using dynamic memory allocation, so the base object size is predictable and known in advance.

All it's doing is reserving *N* times that footprint when you call `reserve(n)`. Once those entries are used, they'll likely need additional allocation, unless, for example, you just keep them empty.

In other words, `sizeof(std::vector<X>)` is predictable. The total *memory cost* of such a structure is a different thing entirely.

If, on the other hand, you had `std::array<std::array<X>>` then it's a whole different story. Those behave a lot more like C arrays.

Comment: So I'll never be sure that no further allocations will happens. Even feeding myObjects using Copy Constructor. Memory allocations can happen later...

Comment: Absolutely not. `std::vector` will need to allocate as you add entries, `reserve()` doesn't preclude that. If you use *up to* that reservation on something with a trivial size like `int` that doesn't require any additional allocation, you should be fine.

Comment: So in this case place a innerVector.reserve(maxInnVec) within ctor of MyObject and do a myObjects.resize(maxItemsToBeAllowed); myObjects.clear(); will preallocate all necessary memory right?

Comment: You might be wildly overthinking this. Why not just pre-populate the structure and be done with it instead of fussing about with `reserve()`? Remember `reserve()` just books a spot for the basic footprint of the `std::vector` container. It can't anticipate that you will then call `reserve()` later if/when one of those things is actually constructed. I'd suggest just making the initial array with N of whatever you need in-place.

Comment: If you're barking up this proverbial tree because you're worried about future allocations then you might want to forget this nested structure and instead create a large `std::vector<int>` that's reserved a significant chunk of memory, then parcel out slices of it as necessary. Maybe you're making some kind of effectively 2D array, in which case a single structure that manages access to that and can handle index calls is way cleaner.

Comment: The way I've seen this done is either A) a custom allocator, or B) a "reserve" array that's sized as necessary (actually sized, not reserved) and that you can carve up into slices. So long as you never alter the size of it, your pointers to slices will be fine, and can even be encapsulated in some kind of lightweight struct.

Comment: I need to understand what I can do in this specific case: allocate all and prevent further allocation...! Array is not the correct solution, since It will be variable due to the values, and iterate trought actual size()...

Answer (score 4):

The size of a type is never unpredicatble. It is always known at compile time, and it never changes through the lifetime of the program. `std::vector` doesn't contain its elements within the memory of the vector object. The vector object contains a few pointers that point to dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::reserve` just ensures a certain number of elements can be created without rallocating the backing storage of the vector. No new elements are created using this function. (I'm ignoring those that need to be move constructed from the existing elements, if a memory reallocation was necessary.)

the following code still would result in the optimal number of allocations of the backing memory:

```
struct MyObject
{
    int someId;
    std::vector<int> innerVector;

    MyObject(int a)
    {
        innerVector.reserve(a);
    }
};

class VectorManager
{
    std::vector<MyObject> m_objects;
public:
    VectorManager() noexcept
    {}

    void ReserveOuter(size_t n)
    {
        m_objects.reserve(n);
    }

    void AddInner(int const count, int const value)
    {
        auto& newObject = m_objects.emplace_back(count); // add a new MyObject constructing it using count as constructor parameter
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            newObject.innerVector.push_back(value);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    VectorManager vm;
    size_t const max = 50;
    vm.ReserveOuter(max); // resize outer vector according to requires max
    for (size_t i = 0; i != max; ++i)
    {
        vm.AddInner(i, i);
    }
}
```

This logic still uses the optimal number of allocations for backing storage of vectors, if the size of the inner vectors is the for all `MyObject`s. The code above would still have only a single allocation for the outer vector at

```
vm.ReserveOuter(max);
```

and one allocation per `MyObject` created caused by

```
vm.AddInner(i, i);
```

You cannot improve on this number without changing the classes, since one allocation per vector is required. (I'm ignoring vectors never getting filled with any elements for simplicity in these statements; The number of allocations would still be optimal, if some of the vectors remain empty.)